# Unicode characters in nginx fastcgi links

Tags: nginx, django, fastcgi

I have a django project hosted over nginx with fastcgi. Django has some urls that user cyrillic characters. But when I try to open page with such link, django tells that it doesn't have such model, because the link got escaped and is taken to django as "%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8". On apache the same project works fine. What option do I need to tell nginx not to escape links like that?

Comment: It might help to do a bit more research first and report back what you've found.

Comment: What research? I haven't found anything like that over the internet, and I don't have any more clues.

Comment: I used https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx for configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fastcgi_param directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) determines what [variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) are passed to the FastCGI application. You may be passing `$request_uri` which is the raw URI while Django expects a decoded URI which is in the `$uri` variable.

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.6> according to the changes... this settings are no longer necessary,
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#ChangedthewayURLpathsaredetermined
I have commented out both the Path info and Script Name lines in fastcgi_params (in Debian-like cases) or in the nginx.conf (RHEL cases)